# How to use bootstrap-table in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-table

I want to use bootstrap-table to refactor pages but it does`t work when integrate with AngularJs?

Can someone tell me how to use it correctly?

Answer (score -1):

AngularJS has nothing to do with BootStrap in general. However, I've bootstrapped a code which demos AngularJS with BootStrap Tables - [Here](https://github.com/codehate/ng/tree/master/ng-repeat%20Filters). [Here is the Demo](http://codehate.github.io/ng/ng-repeat%20Filters/).

Comment: thank you very much,but I was using  [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) not bootstrap tables.There is a big differences between them